# How can I get (and learn to meaningfully interpret) very low-level diagnostics about the Wifi subsystem on my Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid) Linux system?

Tags: linux, wifi, ubuntu-10.04, linux-device-driver, diagnostics

I've dug into NetworkManager (and from there, into dbus, etc.) and identified the wireless driver I'm using (iwlagn); but I'm sure there's more I can learn, if I only knew where to look.

Pointers to tutorials, references (on- or off-line), or howtos would be gratefully appreciated.

(If folks feel that this would be better asked on serverfault.com, or superuser.com, just let me know.)

If it's of interest, here's what `sudo lspci -vvxxx -s 04:0.0` returns:

```
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless WiFi Link 5100
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 1201
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 32
    Region 0: Memory at f2c00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [d0] Message Signalled Interrupts: Mask- 64bit+ Queue=0/0 Enable+
        Address: 00000000fee0100c  Data: 41b1
    Capabilities: [e0] Express (v1) Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <512ns, L1 unlimited
            ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset+
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+ FLReset-
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr+ TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Latency L0 <128ns, L1 <32us
            ClockPM+ Suprise- LLActRep- BwNot-
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- Retrain- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM+ AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting <?>
    Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 04-ed-3b-ff-ff-65-1e-00
    Kernel driver in use: iwlagn
    Kernel modules: iwlagn
00: 86 80 32 42 06 04 10 00 00 00 80 02 10 00 00 00
10: 04 00 c0 f2 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
20: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 86 80 01 12
30: 00 00 00 00 c8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0a 01 00 00
40: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
50: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
60: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
70: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
80: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
90: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
a0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
b0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
c0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 d0 23 c8 00 00 00 0d
d0: 05 e0 81 00 0c 10 e0 fe 00 00 00 00 b1 41 00 00
e0: 10 00 01 00 c0 8e 00 10 10 08 10 00 11 9c 06 00
f0: 40 01 11 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should [enable the debug output of the 802.11 stack in the kernel](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/Reporting_bugs#kernel_messages).

Second, you should compile your kernel (or just the driver module) with debugging output enabled (`CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG`). Here's an excerpt from the Kconfig file:

```
  To set a value, simply echo an 8-byte hex value to the same file:

      % echo 0x43fff > /sys/class/net/wlan0/device/debug_level

  You can find the list of debug mask values in:
      drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwl-debug.h
```

There's also some DebugFS support for the iwlagn (`CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS`).

Third, if you're using WPA or 802.11i (you should), you can kill the NetworkManager and create you're own config file for the wpa_supplicant (check out the [README](http://hostap.epitest.fi/gitweb/gitweb.cgi?p=hostap.git;a=blob_plain;f=wpa_supplicant/README) to see how). Then you can run wpa_supplicant with the `-dd` switch to turn on its debug info.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions about what I should learn/where I might do so, to better understand all this debugging output?

Comment: I didn't know about the wireless-tools package, and it's various lovely tools: iwconfig, iwlist, etc.  I'm delightedly looking around at iwlist now...  Wheee!

Comment: wireless.kernel.org is the main site of interest. You can also take a look at the sources of the drivers. Forget about the wireless-tools package, it's obsolete! Use the `iw` tool instead: http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Documentation/iw

Comment: Here's another excellent-looking source that I hadn't before seen: http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Jean_Tourrilhes/Linux/Linux.Wireless.Overview.html

Comment: At least on Ubuntu 10.04, the README.Debian says: "The tool is currently mainly used for drivers based on the mac80211 stack". I don't know what "the mac80211 stack" means.  Does this refer to the widespread wireless protocol 802.11?  Or?  If I'm using the iwlagn kernel module, am I using it?  I assumed not, but...

Comment: The mac80211 is more like a device driver framework for the wireless cards. See the description: http://linuxwireless.org/en/developers/Documentation/mac80211 Most of the wireless drivers nowadays (iwlagn included!) are based on mac80211.